# Playing sounds one at a time

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Im building a windows phone 8/8.1 app which consists in playing sounds, the way im doing is once i press a button, it fires up the event and runs this code:

```
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Sound/DO_converted.wav", UriKind.Relative));
SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
SoundEffectInstance instance = sound.CreateInstance();
instance.Play();
```

But if i press more then one button i have more then one sound playing at the same time.
So is there anyway to stop this from happening, play one sound at a time?

Greets,
José Correia

Answer (score 0):

Work out what the sound effect duration is. Use a queue to queue them and have a loop that play the next one after the current one's duration.

`SoundEffect` has the following property:

```
public TimeSpan Duration { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, ive also posted this question on Windows dev forum, and this is the best solution for my problem:

[MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/pt-BR/a7b7a2e0-4273-4286-ba6b-de33082f22ee/playing-sounds-one-at-a-time?forum=wpdevelop)

```
      SoundEffectInstance instance;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Sound/test1.wav", UriKind.Relative));
                SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
                if (instance != null)
                    instance.Stop();
                instance = sound.CreateInstance();
                instance.Play();
     }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Sound/test2.wav", UriKind.Relative));
                SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
                if (instance != null)
                    instance.Stop();
                instance = sound.CreateInstance();
                instance.Play();
    }
```